# chrome.devtools.network How can I use that method in devtools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Sorry if I ask easy question

The code is from that link:

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/devtools_network/

```
chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(
  function(request) {
    if (request.response.bodySize > 40*1024) {
      chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval(
          'console.log("Large image: " + unescape("' +
          escape(request.request.url) + '"))');
    }
  }
);
```

When  I copy this code to developer tools console, I got error. My aim is catching web pages whose pagesize(transferred size in network section) info is bigger than treshold value.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NU6GD.png]

How can I get thhe value on the photo programmatcally, I am using above code on this purpose.

Comment: This code is for extensions. You can't run it in devtools console of a web page.

Comment: @wOxxOm how can I downloand extension? I want to run this code, how can I do it?

Comment: You need to write an extension to use this code. What are you trying to do and how is this related to the marked area in your screenshot?

Comment: I want to get transfer size, this code may help?